# R Sum Data inside area vs outside area

Tags: r, sum

I want to check about the feasibility of this before getting too far down the rabbit hole.

I have a series of data points:

```
  TV      TR HV       HR inArea       lon      lat
1  1 1124.65  1 18914.52   TRUE -77.23844 38.70535
2  1  465.25  1 16149.28   TRUE -77.23301 38.75103
3 NA      NA  3 13987.26   TRUE -75.26151 39.76013
4 NA      NA  1 13695.86   TRUE -77.21661 38.75539
5  2 2487.53  1 11971.32   TRUE -77.28368 38.79584
6 NA      NA  1 10065.85   TRUE -77.21252 38.79352
```

What I'd like to do is:

1. Check if a datapoint is inside of a given area (such as SHP of drivetimes from a central point or a formula that calculates drivetimes)
2. Sum the values in the columns that are inside the area
3. BONUS Create choropleths of these areas with the separate column summations on different plots. e.g. a choropleth that displays the SUMS all of column HR for a 2 minute, 5 minute and 10 minute drivetime from a central spot.

I'm poking around for some resources and have found [Drivetimes](http://www.r-bloggers.com/adding-google-drive-times-and-distance-coefficients-to-regression-models-with-ggmap-and-sp/) and [gIntersects](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/rgeos/docs/gIntersects). Does this sound like it's something that could work? Any other methods to point me in would be appreciated too.

Thanks guys!

Comment: This sounds like it could work.  You should add some code with an example of your data and the object you describe in 1.  That would make it easier to help with 2 and 3.

Comment: `rgeos` provides all the tools for checking if points are in/out/on geometries, yes.